# Why is the following reverse triangle inequality true for given series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, proof-writing

I wish to show that

for $(a_k)$ a sequence of numbers, $a_k \in \mathbb{R}$

then claim :

> $|\sum\limits_{k = n+1}^m a_k | \leq ||\sum\limits_{k = n+1}^\infty
>  a_k| - |\sum\limits_{k = m+1}^\infty a_k ||$

I tried to show this by using:

$|\sum\limits_{k = n+1}^m a_k | \leq |\sum\limits_{k = n+1}^\infty a_k - \sum\limits_{k = m+1}^\infty a_k | \leq ||\sum\limits_{k = n+1}^\infty a_k| - |\sum\limits_{k = m+1}^\infty a_k ||$

But I think the last inequality is not necessarily true...

Can someone verify the claim and show and intuitive reason (or a proof) why it is true?

Comment: Are you sure the inequality is in this direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the the assumption that the series $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent: otherwise, the quantity $\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k$ cannot be manipulated (it is not defined).

Furthermore, the inequality that actually holds is in the **other** direction. See below.

---

Assuming the series $\sum_n a_n$ is convergent, you can write:
$$
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k = \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k + \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty a_k
$$ 
so that, by the triangle inequality,
$$
\left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k\right\rvert  \leq \left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k \right\rvert  + \left\lvert \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty a_k \right\rvert 
$$ 
and, rearranging,
$$
\left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k\right\rvert - \left\lvert \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty a_k \right\rvert   \leq \left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k \right\rvert.
$$

---

Similarly,
$$
\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty a_k = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k - \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k
$$ 
so that
$$
\left\lvert \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty a_k\right\rvert  \leq \left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k \right\rvert  + \left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k \right\rvert
$$ 
and, rearranging,
$$
\left\lvert \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty a_k\right\rvert - \left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k \right\rvert   \leq \left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k \right\rvert.
$$

---

Combining the two, we get
$$
\left\lvert\left\lvert \sum_{k=m+1}^\infty a_k\right\rvert - \left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty a_k \right\rvert\right\rvert   \leq \left\lvert \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} a_k \right\rvert.
$$